# How to append 2 data sets one below the other having slightly different column names?

Tags: r

Data set1:

```
ID Name     Territory   Sales
1  Richard  NY            59
8  Sam      California    44
```

Data set2:

```
Terr ID  Name   Comments
 LA   5   Rick    yes
 MH   11  Oly     no
```

I want final data set to have columns of 1st data set only and identify `Territory` is same as `Terr` and does not bring forward `Comments` column.

Final data should look like:

```
ID Name     Territory  Sales
1  Richard  NY           59
8  Sam      California   44
5  Rick     LA           NA
11 Oly      MH           NA
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `rbind(set1, setNames(set2[,-4], names(set1)))`

Comment: or `library(data.table); rbindlist(list(set1, set2[,-4]))`

Comment: My columns are also in not a same order. I have just edited the question, please answer now. Thanks !

Comment: `rbind(set1, setNames(set2[,c(2,3,1)], names(set1)))`

Comment: Please check the question again.. i just changed it. Since my columns are not in same order

Comment: I want to identify it on column names, like if Territory = Terr, append it... something like that.. this is because my data set might not have same order every time i receive the input files.. So want to do it on column names

Comment: `rbind(set1, setNames(set2[, names(sort(unlist(sapply(names(set2), agrep, x = names(set1)))))], names(set1)))`?

Comment: Getting an error : undefined columns selected. Sorry i am new to this.. In case my questions are silly

Comment: Seems to be more complicated than at first sight. I've reopened the question & posted a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
# create a named vector with names from 'set2' 
# with the positions of the matching columns in 'set1'
nms2 <- sort(unlist(sapply(names(set2), agrep, x = names(set1))))

# only keep the columns in 'set2' for which a match is found
# and give them the same names as in 'set1'
set2 <- setNames(set2[names(nms2)], names(set1[nms2]))

# bind the two dataset together

# option 1:
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(set1, set2)

# option 2:
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(set1, set2), fill = TRUE)
```

which gives (`dplyr`-output shown):

> ```
>   ID    Name  Territory Sales
> 1  1 Richard         NY    59
> 2  8     Sam California    44
> 3  5    Rick         LA    NA
> 4 11     Oly         MH    NA
> ```

---

Used data:

```
set1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 8L), 
                       Name = c("Richard", "Sam"),
                       Territory = c("NY", "California"),
                       Sales = c(59L, 44L)),
                  .Names = c("ID", "Name", "Territory", "Sales"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
set2 <- structure(list(Terr = c("LA", "MH"),
                       ID = c(5L, 11L),
                       Name = c("Rick", "Oly"),
                       Comments = c("yes", "no")),
                  .Names = c("Terr", "ID", "Name", "Comments"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```